# Accessing Fields in a Class in Java

Tags: java, class, object, field

I apologize for the mistakes as this is my first post here.  This is a basic question but I do not understand the answers I've seen.  In the following Java code:

```
public class RAPVAR_XDATA_TYPE{

        public class datacfg{
            public int datacfg_len;
            public float datacfg_val;
        }

        public class numdata{
            public int numdata_len;
            public float numdata_val;
        }

        public class strdata{
            public int strdata_len;
            public String strdata_val;
        }
}
```

Why can I not access numdata_len in the following fashion:

```
RAPVAR_XDATA_TYPE.numdata.numdata_len = 1;

RAPVAR_XDATA_TYPE rxt = new RAPVAR_XDATA_TYPE();
rxt.numdata.numdata_len = 1;
```

I am trying to build a data structure to mimic the same structure I did in c++ a while ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to make the inner classes **and** their fields static for this to work, but before you do this, don't. Don't try to make C++ structures with Java as that's not the Java way, and will lead to poorly constructed Java programs. Instead get a good book on OOP and Java such as "Thinking in Java" and a book on design patterns such as the GoF book or the Head First book, and learn the Java "way".

Comment: The problem with not trying to make c++ structures with Java is I need a data structure that the RPC server will "understand".  In addition I have to have a properly formed container to receive the response.  I was (am) new to c++ but I was able to successfully cobble together working DLLs for the other programmers to use.  Now I am attempting the same thing for use an Android tablet.  I have Java ONCRPC libraries now I just have to get the data structures right.

Comment: So I compared the Java and the c++ rpc libraries.  I get it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to consider that what you have in a class is a 'pattern' for the the data elements an instance of the class will contain.  in your example you also have an inner class which is just a nested 'pattern'.  Even if you new the  outer class you have not created space for the item in the inner class.  you would need a constructor that new-ed (instantiated) the inter class objects and set references to them in the instance of your outer class to have something 'like' what you had in c++.